# fill 2d array with 1d array java

Tags: java, matrix

I have an matrix and an array and I want to fill matrix from the array values.

```
float [][] mat = new float [m][n];
float [] array= new float [3];
```

For example :

arr = {1, 2, 3}

mat with size 4*4

mat =

```
        {1, 2, 3, 1

         2, 3, 1, 2

         3, 1, 2, 3

         1, 2, 3, 1}
```

What is the way to fill the matrix?

Comment: Not sure what you want. Can you clarify ?

Comment: I have a function that calculate in each iteration the values of array and i want fill the matrix mat with size m*n from value of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you want to use the values in the array to insert in line in the matrix.

First, let's build our matrix and array values :

```
int m = 3;
int n = 5;
float[][] mat = new float[m][n];
float[] array = {1,2,3,4};
```

Then, iterate the matrix to prepare the update :

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        // update here
    }
}
```

So, what you want is to use the array to set the value, when you reach the end, you start over. There is two solution I see :

## Using an index

We increment it but use the modulo to get back to "0" when we reach the length of the array.

```
int currentIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        mat[i][j] = array[currentIndex];
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1 ) % array.length;
    }
}
```

## Using the matrix coordinate

Or you can get the index by doing the sum of both index of the matrix then using the modulo again, this allow to update any value without a loop, (if needed)

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        mat[i][j] = array[(i+j)%array.length];
    }
}
```

*One problem with this solution, you will not get the correct output for a matrix where `m + n > Integer.MAX_VALUE` simply because the sum will give a negative value, give an incorrect index.*

## Output

You can see the result using :

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(mat));
```

Both solution give :

```
[
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0],
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0],
    [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to specify second array size: `float [][] mat = new float [m][];`

Here is an example how to declare matrix of array:

```
int m = 5;
float[][] mat = new float[m][];
float[] array = new float[3];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    mat[i] = array;
}
```

Comment: The height of mat not equal to three

Comment: Ok, what we need to do with array if you want to create matrix m * n?

Comment: Yes i want create matrix m*n and fill them with array values

Comment: Just for fun, update `mat[0][0] = 5` and `mat[1][0] = 10` and see the result for both value !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by mat [0][0] = 5 and mat [1][0] = 10

Comment: @rouin It is using a unique `array` in the matrix, if you change a cell in one `array`, it will be change in the other too (since this is the same object). So `mat[0][0] == mat[1][0] == mat[2][0]` is always true even if you change only one of those cell.